# How to use Vuex with asynchronous computed setter property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vue-component, vuex

I have the following component where I have a `theme` computed property. The `set` function of the computed property executes a Vuex action called `setTheme` which returns a promise and also updates the `theme` property in the Vuex state.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input id="light-theme-radio" v-model="theme" type="radio" value="light">
    <label for="light-theme-radio">Light</label>

    <input id="dark-theme-radio" v-model="theme" type="radio" value="dark">
    <label for="dark-theme-radio">Dark</label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import { createNamespacedHelpers } from "vuex";

const { mapActions } = createNamespacedHelpers("theme");

export default {
  computed: {
    theme: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.theme.theme;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.setTheme(value);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["setTheme"])
  }
};
</script>
```

The trouble is that the `theme.get` computed property is not being called after the `setTheme` is finished to update the radio buttons with the newly selected item. What is the best way around this problem when using asynchronous setters. This is what my Vuex looks like:

```
export const state = {
  theme: "light"
};

export const mutations = {
  theme: (s, p) => (s.theme = p)
};

export const actions: ActionTree = {
  async setTheme(context, theme) {
    context.commit("theme/theme", theme);
    // ...omitted
    await Timer.delay(750);
    // ...omitted
  }
};

const mainModule = {
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations,
  namespaced: true,
  state
};
export default mainModule;

const modules = {
  other: otherModule,
  theme: themeModule
};

const store = new Store({
  modules,
});
export default store;
```

Comment: during the period waiting for promise is resolved, what do you want to render?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the problem you met is both radio buttons have **checked** effect which is caused by Vue doesn't render in time.

So the solution is let Vue renders first, then waiting for the promise. Once finished, render again.

Below is **two approaches**:

1. uses `vm.$forceUpdate`
2. commit one fake value like `loading...`, Vue will render first (Vue is data driven), after real value comes up, Vue will auto-render again.

Below is one simple demo:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    theme: "light"
  },
  mutations: {
    theme: (s, p) => (s.theme = p)
  },
  actions: {
    setTheme: async function (context, theme) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(()=> {
          context.commit("theme", theme)
          resolve('done')
        }, 1500)
      })
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data() {
    return {
      updatedCount: 1
    }
  },
  computed: {
    theme: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.theme
      },
      set(value) {
        //or use this.$forceUpdate() instead
        this.$store.commit("theme", 'loading...') //or other values
        this.setTheme(value)
      }
    }
  },
  updated(){
    console.log('updated', this.updatedCount++)
  },
  methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapActions(["setTheme"])
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <h3>{{theme}}</h3>
    <input id="light-theme-radio" v-model="theme" type="radio" value="light">
    <label for="light-theme-radio">Light</label>

    <input id="dark-theme-radio" v-model="theme" type="radio" value="dark">
    <label for="dark-theme-radio">Dark</label>
  </div>
</div>
```